# Podio Webhooks limitation using Zapier

Tags: webhooks, podio, zapier

I am currently using Zapier with Podio as a trigger. I have around 20 zaps triggered from Podio actions.
A few days ago I changed my Podio password, and when I reconnected my Podio account in Zapier, it seems like a webhooks limitation took place.
Is that possible? Can you please help me with that?

Thx in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please explain in more details what kind of webhook limitation you got?

Comment: according to a Zapier engineer, I've reached a limitation of webhooks (10) per field in a specific app.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is not related to your Podio password and reconnection of your Podio account. This is usual Podio limitation for number of webhooks per app_field (this is not per app but individual field).

Please consider re-designing your flows and apps to workaround this.

---

To get list of all webhooks that you have for specific app_field: http://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/get-hooks-215285

To delete unneeded webhooks:
https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/delete-hook-215291

All other hook related methods: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks

Comment: Thx for your answer.
I knew about this limitation already, but it appears that even when all my zaps are off, some webhooks remains. Maybe some older ones?
I know that bacause I did the test with a Zapier engineer.

Comment: Maybe, sorry but you can only check that yourself. Here is webhooks Podio documentation where you can find more information: https://developers.podio.com/examples/webhooks. You probably want to check all webhooks that you might have for specific app_field, then this method is for you: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/get-hooks-215285

Comment: OK perfect, I now have the list of the unwanted webhooks. I need a process to remove them, unsubscribe from them or anything that can free up the slots out of the 10 available per field.
Can I do this for myself, or is there only a tech from Podio who can do this task?

Thx for your help.

Comment: Podio team don't have access to your stuff, but it should be pretty easy to remove unneeded hooks. Here are details for that: https://developers.podio.com/doc/hooks/delete-hook-215291